# TCP/IP Application without silly window avoidance

Tags: tcp

Does anybody know if an application is sending data that is too small(5 bytes only per segment) and there is no silly window avoidance. In this case what max. perecentage of network bandwidth can be used for this data. At lower layers are ethernet and Ipv4.

Do I need to add all the headers?i.e.Ethernet,Ipv4 and TCP? Or just TCP?

Comment: Such a system wouldn't comply with RFC 1122 #4.2.3.3-4.

Comment: Yep but what will be the network bandwidth utilization in this case?

Comment: What's the path MTU size between your two endpoints? Use that to work out your utilisation.